# Angular Http.post method not working/ not posting my data to Server

Tags: php, angular, typescript, codeigniter-3

I try to post my data to Server using angular(Angular CLI: 1.7.3)  Http.post() method. but it dosn't work. I used php Server.

typescript Function

```
private url = 'http://localhost/...../post'; // my URL
constructor (private http : Http){ }

addData () {
    this.http.post(this.url, {name:'MyName'}) // **
        .subscribe(responce => {
            console.log(responce);
        });
}
```

PHP Function (use CodeIgniter)

```
public function post(){
    echo 'backend working.. ';
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

I try this (for **)

```
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({name:'MyName'}))
```

& this

```
this.http.post(this.url, {name:'MyName'}, { headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) })
```

& this

```
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({name:'MyName'}), { headers: new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) })
```

& this

```
this.http.post(this.url, {name:'MyName'}, new RequestOptions({headers : new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) }) )
```

& this

```
this.http.post(this.url, JSON.stringify({name:'MyName'}), new RequestOptions({headers : new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) }) )
```

but dosn't work anything for me.. :(

console log => 
    backend working.. Array↵(↵)↵

I used CodeIgniter(CodeIgniter-3.1.8) for Backend. How I resolve this problem????

Comment: You have to be more specific about the error, not working does not help us identify the problem. Please add the error

Comment: nothing to show any error. only can't see my name.(posted data)

Comment: you are making a `post`, what's the response payload when you examine `network` on developer tools?

Comment: @Reshan He didn't mention errors. Can you put what you can observe in the developer tools network tab? May be 400 HttpStatus Code etc. Btw why don't you use HttpClientModule?